# How can I set a message on the page I am `drupal-goto`ing towards?

Tags: 7, redirection

I have a page which makes certain verifications and needs to redirect the user in certain cases. In those cases, I want the destination page to show a message, but I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
if ($userNeedsToBeRedirected) {
  drupal_set_message(null, "You've been redirected because ...");
  drupal_goto('destination');
}
```

The redirection works, but the message doesn't appear. What can I do?

**Note**: I also tried the following:

```
if ($userNeedsToBeRedirected) {
  drupal_goto('destination', array(
    'query' => array(
      'message' => "You've been redirected because ..."
    )
  ));
}
```

and in the destination page:

```
if (isset($_GET['message'])) {
  drupal_set_message(null, $_GET['message']);
}
```

but is doesn't work either because (I believe) `drupal_set_message` is being called too late the the page creation process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting a NULL message in [drupal_set_message](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7), the correct syntax would be:

```
if ($userNeedsToBeRedirected) {
  drupal_set_message("You've been redirected because ...");
  drupal_goto('destination');
}
```

The second `drupal_set_message` `$type` parameter is for the message type:

- 'status'
- 'warning'
- 'error'